# Is it possible to attach a USB device, such as a mobile phone, to a Windows 7 PC and have the PC only charge the device?

Tags: windows-7, usb, power, charging

Is it possible to attach a USB device, such as a mobile phone, to a Windows 7 PC and *not* have any drivers used or installed?  IOW, to *only* use the USB port on the Windows 7 PC as a charging port?

If so, please specify if your answer is applicable to USB2, USB3, or USB Type-C ports.

I would prefer a Windows setting (registry, or otherwise) or other software technique, but I am open to all answers.

Comment: Not sure if this really answers your question exactly, but it's a means to the same end. They make USB cables that are charge-only and do not allow data transfer, like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/PortaPow-Micro-USB-Cable-Charging/dp/B0088HTYUE).

Comment: @n8te Great find! :)  It doesn't help at the moment (and isn't free), but it's great to know that product exists.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave - but he said it doesn't really help him at the moment, so I was assuming it wouldn't be an accepted answer,

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't directly address OP's desire for a simple Windows registry fix type solution, one option for people looking to charge their phones through a PC's USB port but don't want any possibility of data exchange is to simply buy a charge-only USB cable such as the type discussed in this [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/140225/how-can-i-tell-charge-only-usb-cables-from-usb-data-cables) discussion. An example of such cable sold in stores can be found [here.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088HTYUE)

Comment: `Although it doesn't directly address OP's desire for a simple Windows registry fix type solution` OP never asked for that. OP states `...to only use the USB port on the Windows 7 PC as a charging port` +1